# Backup of Postgres database

Tags: postgresql, backup, pgadmin

I want to create a backup of my database in Postgres.
I'm using pgAdmin.

- on my database I have clicked right button of mouse
- after that I've selected the "Create a backup of database"

After that I've got a sequence of messages:

```
C:\Program Files\pgAdmin III\1.12\pg_dump.exe --host localhost --port 5432 --username "postgres" --role "postgres" --no-password  --verbose --file "E:\wfr.backup" "WFR"
pg_dump: server version: 9.1.1; pg_dump version: 9.0.3
pg_dump: aborting because of server version mismatch
pg_dump: *** aborted because of error
```

Why didn't it create a backup and return the error instead?

Comment: You have pgAdminIII that is compatible with PostgreSQL 9.0 but the server is PostgreSQL 9.1. Get new pgAdminIII.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pgAdmin III 1.12 does not support PostgreSQL 9.1. So better upgrade your pgAdmin III to version 1.14 or newer.

Comment: Is there a PgAdmin IV? Could you give me a link to download it?

Comment: I've linked to the most recent version in my answer.

Comment: http://www.postgresql.org/ftp/pgadmin3/release/v1.14.1/win32/       here you can download..

Comment: It was the fault of version of PgAdmin. When I have downloaded and installed a version which vijikumar post above, the problem disappear. Thank you all for a help!

Answer (score 1):

There's a difference between pg_dump on the system running pg_dump and postgres on your database server that's too big for them to be considered compatible. Find out what version of postgres is on your server and then install the same version of pg_dump locally.

[The most recent version of PgAdmin](http://www.postgresql.org/ftp/pgadmin3/release/v1.14.1/win32/) will support your database. You're a couple releases behind.